# Shall we remove or blasklist the [design] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist-request

This one's actually even broader than the [user-interface tag we blacklisted](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/should-we-blacklist-the-user-interface-tag). Is there any possible reason we should keep the [design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag?

Answer (score 1):

No reason at all. Blacklist it and we'll have alot to do until Xmas

Comment: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: Damn, I know this. It's too early (7 o'clock) for me to think spelling after an eight hour session assembling IKEA furniture. Thank you a lot :-)